# Create different virtual devices that corresponds to different width breakpoint

Tags: java, android, android-studio, responsive-design, android-virtual-device

I'm developing android application and I want to support multiple screen sizes.

for this I have checked the documentation and it's recommended to create different layout for the width breakpoints like below

- 480dp
- 600dp
- 840dp
  .. and so on

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali

So I have created those layouts using smallest width qualifier as `fragment_shoe_detail(sw480dp)`
and so on.

Now I want to test those on virtual devices for each width. But I don't know how to create it.
If I tried to create new virtual device I can choose its size in inches , resolution and density dpi but now the width dp.

Comment: If you just want to test how it looks a simple solution without creating emulators is to use [Layout Validation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#layout-validation)

Comment: @javdromero Thanks for the reply but actually I want to understand how can I map the width in dp to virtual devices